# Updating TFS 2012 express RTM to Update 4

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am using Team Foundation Serve 2012 11.0.50727.1 (RTM) . I want to update it. I got some [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=38190) for update 4. But this link downloads full setup of TFS 2012. So if i want to apply this update should i install it directly as we update other software or it is upgrade which requires tasking backup of my current tfs server and restore backup after update? So what are the steps to be taken before updating TFS 2012 express RTM? Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

The TFS installer for a new install or an upgrade is the same installer.  It is highly recommended to take a backup before you do the upgrade.

The installer is broken into two phases: install, configure.  When you run it it will first install all the bits/files to your machine (no options to choose on this step).  Then it will run the configuration wizard which will detect you are doing an upgrade and walk you through the upgrade steps.